# Picasso image loading not working

Tags: android, api, android-recyclerview, retrofit, picasso

I want to display product images for an e-comm app please let me know what is wrong with my code for which it's not displaying the image inside Recycler view.

RecyclerAdapter Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Record_> mitems = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context mcontext;


public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Record_> mitems, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, Context mcontext) {
    this.mitems = mitems;
    this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
}
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Record_> items) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from((Context) context);
    this.mitems = items;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_display_layout,parent,false);
    /*ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mcontext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    ));*/
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Picasso.with(mcontext).load(mitems.get(position).getProductImageUrl());
    //holder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mitems.get(position).getProductImageUrl()));
    //Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext());
    Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(mitems.get(position).getProductImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    holder.mtextView.setText(mitems.get(position).getProductDescription() );
    holder.priceTv.setText("$"+mitems.get(position).getSkuFinalPrice());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mitems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView mtextView, priceTv;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.ivProduct);
        mtextView =  view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTV);
        priceTv = view.findViewById(R.id.priceTV);
}
```

ProductDisplayActivity.java

```
public class ProductDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_display);
recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.products);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
getProducts(pod);
private void getProducts(String id) {
        CategoryInterface productInterface =RetrObj.getRetro().create(CategoryInterface.class);
        Call<ProductRespose> productCall = productInterface.getRecords(id);
        //productCall = productInterface.getProductImageUrl(id);
        productCall.enqueue(new Callback<ProductRespose>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProductRespose> call, Response<ProductRespose> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                if(statusCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    ProductRespose productRecord = response.body();
                    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(ProductDisplayActivity.this,productRecord.getRecords().get(0).getAttributes().getRecords());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
//                    recyclerView.notify();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProductRespose> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ProductDisplayActivity.this, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am fetching the data from API using Retrofit, the list is being displayed in recycler view but the images are not coming from the product. I have used Picasso to display image but please let me know the error.

Comment: could you show us your api response? json?

Comment: also your xml file

Comment: are you sure that your image URLs are correct?

Comment: also have you checked logcat for warnings or errors?

Comment: Yes image URLs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the error you could try to put this inside the adapter, and then check logcat:

```
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
      {
        exception.printStackTrace();
      }
   });
   builder.build().load(URL).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly where to add the above code?

Comment: inside "onBindViewHolder" in your adapter, with that in place you will be able to see the error